# Save and access file on a webserver and localhost

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-mvc-4, upload, appharbor

I would like to save a file on a webserver from my fully-working fileupload control. I have received the `HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];` and I would like to save it on my server.

My servers is called "appharbor" ( https://appharbor.com/ ) and it's specification say, that I have file write access for `Path.getTempPath();` folder.

My code for saving the file is:

```
HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
string dirrectoryPath =Path.GetTempPath();
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
string mapPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(dirrectoryPath);
Directory.CreateDirectory(mapPath);
string fileFullPath = Path.Combine(mapPath, fileName);
file.SaveAs(fileFullPath);
myModel.uri = fileFullPath;
```

How I can remake this code in a working way?

View:

```
String pdf = "http://docs.google.com/gview?url=" + @Model.uri + "&embedded=true";
<iframe src="@pdf" style="width:100%; height: 1000px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

### As You can see, we are ONLY trying to DISPLAY the file on webpage. Not allowing the user to download it (no special restrictions for it, however).

**EDIT**

Detailed information what happens now and with slight change:

When I have

```
string dirrectoryPath = Path.GetTempPath();
```

then that occurs on server:

```
POST http://warsztatynet.apphb.com/api/upload 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

and that occurs locally

```
An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: 'C:/Users/Tunczyk/AppData/Local/Temp/' expected virtual path.
```

And I suspect that they're exactly the same thing, becaue both of these happen in same function.

`Path.GetTempPath();` its App_Data folder on webserver and on localhost

When I have

```
string dirrectoryPath ="~/App_Data";
```

then that occurs on server:

```
GET http://c/Users/MyPath/sample.rtf 404 (Not Found)
```

and that occurs locally:

```
GET http://c/Users/MyPath/sample.rtf 404 (Not Found)
```

---

**EDIT 2**
It's answer for Caótico fanegas post:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/Users/apphb5dac91d9317868/AppData/Local/Temp/glyphicons-halflings.png
```

This is what happens when I do it like that:

```
string dirrectoryPath = Path.GetTempPath();
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
Directory.CreateDirectory(dirrectoryPath);
string fileFullPath = Path.Combine(dirrectoryPath, fileName);
file.SaveAs(fileFullPath);
```

Guys I'm looking for easiest way to do this. Its not commercial application. It is just for university.

---

**EDIT 3**

To be more understandable, I will give You a link to my application:
[MyWebsite](http://warsztatynet.apphb.com/)
To test it You have to:

1. press Course Creation Tab
2. Press button +
3. choose any lesson Schema by pressing it
4. Press any of coloured divs
5. Choose a file type from list
6. Upload file

There Should be displayed Your file, but it isn't (in main are of the view - clicked div).

I recomend to use Google Chrome because at other browser You may have some visual problems.

Comment: Also, you'll likely need to write a custom handler that can read files saved in the temp folder, as MVC won't read a file from a temp path unless it's included in your routes.

Comment: Updated the post, it now contains the information "what happens", @ppittle .

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to store the file anywhere inside the provided path, and then use an action to retrieve that file, using the FileResult action result

```
public FileResult file(string fileName)
{
    return File(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
}
```

This is not the full solution, but should put you in the right track.

Comment: Do You, suggest, that it isn't possible to 

1. save a file

2. store the path to file

3. use the path for whatever purpose in mvc4?

So I have to use that FileResult for getting my file in view? I need only accessible file path for that which is stored in my nice model.

Comment: You need a separate controller that can take the filename.  From your view you would use something like @Url.Action("Download", "File", Model.Uri );

Comment: Yes it's possible, but I wouldn't recommend it. The correct way to access a flie is always through an action. This way you can control access permissions and such. Linking to static routes is ok for publicly available content, like decorations, images, css, and stuff, not for user uploaded content. I strongly suggest that you use an action/controller for dowloads.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like`HttpPostedFile.SaveAs()`expects a virtual path to save files. The`"~/App_data"`approach should work if you don't translate it to local path through `Server.MapPath()`.

If by any chance you are forced to save to TempPath (trouble with permissions, for instance), I guess you could use the`Stream.CopyTo()`method to save the file on a random physical path.

```
using (var newFile = System.IO.File.Create("local_path"))
{
    fil.InputStream.CopyTo(newFile);
}
```

This code comes straight from my head, and so, is not 100% reliable. Might need some work.

Comment: As You can see, I have updated the question with details, what happens when I have followed Your suggestion.